# Add Cognito Authorizer to Api Gateway LambdaRestAPI in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I am trying to add a Cognito Authorizer to an existing API Gateway `LambdaRestApi`. It is a full proxy integration, and I would like the Authorizer to apply by default to all methods. I can't see from the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.LambdaRestApi.html#addwbrrequestwbrvalidatorid-props) any indicator how to accomplish this via CDK.

What I have:

```
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "TestUsers", {
      userPoolName: "This is a test"
    });

const proxyApi = new apig.LambdaRestApi(this, "HelloFoodSecureProxyApi", {
      handler: proxyHandlerLambdaFunction
    });

// proxyApi.addDefaultAuthorizor(userPool)
```

Best I can tell, I will have to revert to using a raw `RestApi`, add a `Resource` and `Method` that covers my entire API, and manually override the underlying CFN with something like `GET_resource.add_property_override("AuthorizerId", {"Ref": authorizor.auth_id})`

Am I missing something? Any tips for this? Would rather not unspool my entire API (handily `proxy`d to in code) into infrastructure if I can help it.

Answer (score 11):

Using `defaultMethodOptions` worked for me:

```
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "TestUsers", {
    userPoolName: "This is a test"
});

const authorizer = new apig.CognitoUserPoolsAuthorizer(this, 'Authorizer', {
    cognitoUserPools: [userPool]
});

const proxyApi = new apig.LambdaRestApi(this, "HelloFoodSecureProxyApi", {
    handler: proxyHandlerLambdaFunction,
    defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: apig.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
        authorizer
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I had to drop down into the raw CFN elements from CDK. Not sure if there is a better way to do this, I believe the answer really is "don't just use the `LambdaRestApi for anything more serious`".

```
const userPool = new cognito.UserPool(this, "TestUsers", {
      userPoolName: "This is a test"
    });

const proxyApi = new apig.LambdaRestApi(this, "HelloFoodSecureProxyApi", {
      handler: proxyHandlerLambdaFunction
    });

// add an authorizer
const auth = new apig.CfnAuthorizer(this, "Authorizor", {
      restApiId: secureProxyApi.restApiId,
      type: apig.AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
      providerArns: [userPool.userPoolArn],
      name: "CognitoAuthorizor",
      // REQUIRED - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/2561
      identitySource: "method.request.header.Authorization"
    });

// Find the proxy node, its Method node, and add an authorizer
const proxy = secureProxyApi.root.node.findChild("{proxy+}") as apig.ProxyResource;
const anyMethod = proxy.anyMethod?.node.defaultChild as apig.CfnMethod;
anyMethod.addPropertyOverride("AuthorizationType", "COGNITO_USER_POOLS")
anyMethod.addPropertyOverride("AuthorizerId", {"Ref": auth.logicalId})
```